# How does HTML/CSS determine the size?

Tags: html, css, layout

I can't wrap my head around how the HTML/CSS **size computation algorithm** works. Actually I couldn't find any usable description. *Is there any?*

I tried to scale down my current problem and ended up with something like this. Make a 200x50 div and put a 2x2 table in.

```
/* just to see it */
body {background-color: yellow;}
table {background-color: #FFF;}
input {background-color: #EEE;}

/* the only sizes given absolutely */
#demo {width: 200px; height: 50px;}

/* make all components fill their parent */
/* I know that using * is bad! */
#demo * {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

/* no extras */
#demo * {padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px;}
#demo table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px;}
```

Now the puzzle starts, as a cell's relative height seems to be relative to the table rather than the row, **is it true?**

```
#demo tr, #demo td {height: 50%;}
#demo td {width: 50%;}
```

Now I set some colors and try to use `margin` on an input. The good news is that there are no incompatibilities. The output is terrible in all browsers I've tried:

- The columns aren't `50%`. Nor the rows. Actually nothing is 50%.
- The table is `bigger` than its contained `div`.
- It's taller but not wider, why?

Something like this happened even without tables. I just moved a nice-looking innocuous component somewhere else and everything went off. *What's going on here?*

[The full example](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/test.html)

I could understand it when I defined the size as fixed, but I didn't. Naively changing the width to 40% (in order to leave some free room) doesn't help either. I suppose the problem is related to packing everything tightly, which I actually don't need (something like [0cm plus 1fil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/what-is-the-difference-between-fil-and-fill) or [grow](http://migcalendar.com/miglayout/cheatsheet.html) would do.

Comment: Uhh, what? Have you read about CSS sizing rules? The box model, paddings, margins, differing unit types _and_ how different element interact with each other? It's very difficult to determine what exactly you are asking here. At least for me..

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks My very first question (1st paragraph) was about a usable description. The other important question was a bit implicit: How to make this not happen, i.e., *how to make equal column width which doesn't get ruined by the cell content.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'll ever understand this ****, but

- the differences between horizontal and vertical behavior are explained by [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).
- a much saner behavior can be achieved via [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)